# Why is KVO sending a change notification when both the new and old values are the same?

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-observing

I have an entity which is a subclass of NSManagedObject called Event. I have also registered a few modeled attributes of this entity for KVO change notifications:

```
[self.event addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"numGuests"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                context:&numGuestsContext];

[self.event addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"checkedIn"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                context:&checkedInContext];

[self.event addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"seatedCount"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                context:&seatedContext];
```

However it seems the observeValueForKeyPath method notification is getting triggered even though the value of NSKeyValueChangeOldKey and NSKeyValueChangeNewKey in the change dictionary are equal???

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
    NSNumber *oldValue = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    NSNumber *newValue = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    if ([oldValue isEqualToNumber:newValue])
    {
        return;
    }
```

For now i have resorted to just doing a quick sanity check to see if they are equal but i would like to understand why this notification is getting fired to begin with?

**UPDATE**: @jszumski mentioned in the comments that this most likely is happening because the objects are different although logically equal. The Event entity object always has the same address however the object i am observing, which is an attribute within the entity, keeps changing addresses although i am not sure why??

I am wondering if accessing this value in a bg query thread could cause Core Data to create new internal objects within the entity with the same value?

Comment: Are `oldValue` and `newValue` distinct objects that are logically equal?

Comment: I don't understand? The method is triggered because you have updated some property (that you are observing) in your `NSManagedObject` subclass. It is always triggered regardless if the old and new values are the same.

Comment: @jszumski It looks like this may be the case. The Event entity object always has the same address however the object i am observing, which is an attribute within the entity, keeps changing addresses although i am not sure why?? Could Core Data be creating new objects within the entity on fetches?

Comment: This "Question" had my expected "Answer" SWEEETTT!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply, you are assuming the functionality of the [`NSKeyValueObservingOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). They do not work as you are expecting them to. The flags you send only *decide what the contents of the change dictionary are*. The observer is **always** triggered whenever the setters are called.

Besides, when you are sending flags **old** and **new**, that really just says "I would like the old value, and new value. I don't care if they are equal or not".

Please read the reference to learn more:

> NSKeyValueObservingOptions
>
> These constants are passed to addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:
>   and determine the values that are returned as part of the change
>   dictionary passed to an
>   observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:. You can pass 0 if you
>   require no change dictionary values.

Comment: Hi, i understand what the flags are doing. I included them to illustrate that the value of old vs new is the same. I was under the impression that observer should only be triggered if the **value changes**. As mentioned in my update i believe the issue has to do with the object address being different but its value being the same.

Comment: @s.newave That's what I pointed out in bold, right? The observer is **always** triggered. calling the setter or `will/didChangeValueForKeypath:`. Whether they are equal or not is not taken into consideration. You should do the check on your own.

Comment: Mazyod is right about the default behavior - it always notifies. If you want to implement an object that only notifies when the value actually changes, you would have to override `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` to return `NO` for the key(s) in question, then you would have to implement setters for each key that looked for equality, and then only call `-will/didChangeValueForKey:` if the values were actually different. If you don't have control over the implementation of the observed object, you can subclass, but generally speaking, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Mazyod I don't think that'd work.  How would a swizzled `willChangeValueForKey:` know whether or not the value was about to change?

Comment: @Mazyod: `-will/didChangeValueForKey:` don't have access to the change dictionary.

Comment: @ipmcc oops, I meant to say `observeValueForKeyPath:...`.  swizzle in a custom `observeValueForKeyPath:...` that checks if there is change, however, that's probably risky and bad. (removed erroneous comments)